# MySQL find MIN() from duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like below:

**Product Table**

```
PID       CODE
1        a
2        b
```

**Price Table**

```
PrID    PID(ID from Product)   UMID(ID from UOM)  Price
1         1                        1               10
2         1                        2                5
3         2                        1               10
```

**UOM Table**

```
UMID           UM_NAME         UM_RATE
1               BOX              5
2               PC               10
```

I want to get `product` with `price` and that `uom` which has min `UM_RATE`. For example, product `CODE a` has two prices but the prices are different for different `uom`. What I want to achieve is,

```
PID     CODE    PrID    Price     UM_NAME     UM_RATE
1        a       1       10         BOX          5 
2        b       3       10         BOX         5
```

Because box has min `UM_RATE`. I have tried the following query,

```
SELECT product.*, price.*, uom.um_name, MIN(uom.um_rate)
FROM product
LEFT JOIN price ON price.pid = product.pid
LEFT JOIN uom ON price.umid = uom.umid
GROUP BY product.pid
```

This query gives me the following result,

```
PID     CODE    PrID    Price     UM_NAME     UM_RATE
1        a       1       10         PC          5 
2        b       3       10         BOX         5
```

which is wrong. because `UM_RATE` *5* is belong to `UM_NAME` box.
How can I get the expected result?

Comment: That query is invalid and will raise an error on newer MySQL versions. (You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.)

Comment: Why isn't product `b` included in the desired result set? It is linked with `UOM` having the minimum rate.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos sorry I forgot to write `b` in expected result.

Comment: There is also an error in `UM_RATE` value of the first record of the result that you get with your query.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I am using v5.6.43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use join and corelated subquery

```
    select * from (select distinct p.*,u.UMID as uid,
 u.UM_NAME,u.UM_RATE,pr.code from
 price p join uom  u on p.UMID=u.UMID
  join product pr on pr.PID=p.PID
  ) a
  where a.UM_RATE =(select min(UM_RATE) from 
                    (select  p.*,u.UMID as uid,
 u.UM_NAME,u.UM_RATE,pr.code from
 price p join uom  u on p.UMID=u.UMID
  join product pr on pr.PID=p.PID) t where t.code=a.code

      )


prid    PID     UMID    price   uid     UM_NAME     UM_RATE     code
1       1       1       10      1       Box           5          a
3       2       1       10      1       Box           5          b
```

Comment: Bhaiya ai query ta product code `a` er 2ta row return korche. cause product code `a` er 2ta price ache. amar expected result holo jei row te `UM_RATE` kom ache

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar fiddle link  please ?

Comment: or you could do corelated subquery on 2nd step btw fiddle link is helpful to solve problem

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=89ec89145fdd79cfb9e76697caf00103  can you please check this solution

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar how you show both name UM_NAME box and pc as you got the lowest rate so it should be same name . am i right?

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar there is another error in your sample output that prid